# Launch image not working correctly no matter what

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, launch

I'm trying to set a launch image to my application, however, it will not work the right way no matter what I do.

My app is landscape only(left or right), but I though I would just put a portrait launch image anyways.

The launch image only shows up if I check the "portrait" box and uncheck the "Landscape left" and "Landscape right" boxes in the "Deployment Info" settings. Obviously I can't do that because it will mess up my whole app.

I tried changing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to return YES in all of my view controllers, but that didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
-Xerif

Comment: Are you on iPhone or iPad? What Xcode version? What iOS SDK version?

Comment: The app is for iPhone. I've tested it with IOS simulator and my actual phone. I'm running xcode 5, and I searched the web to find out how to get my IOS SDK version and it said to go to About this mac>More info>System report>Software>Developer and this is what it says http://i.imgur.com/ncV5bfg.png

Comment: Erm - can you not just rotate your image 90 degrees and then add as a landscape launch ?

Comment: I've tried rotating it and it still doesn't work in landscape.

Is there a way I could set the app to portrait and then change it to landscape before the view loads?

Comment: Forgot to mention this, when I do rotate the image I get an error saying that it should be 640x960 but it's 960x640.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact probably as your having and unfortunately i have found out that this is a glitch/bug in the Xcode software. I have come up with code that can display a launch image in landscape mode without any size requirements! Try to keep up with me and message me if you have any problems. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new objective-c file with a subclass of NSObject. Name it GameData.
2. inside GameData.h enter this code:

   ```
      #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

      @interface GameData : NSObject


     @property (assign, nonatomic) int Mainint;


      +(instancetype)sharedGameData;

      @end
   ```
3. Now inside of GameData.m enter this code:

   ```
     #import "GameData.h"

    @implementation GameData


     + (instancetype)sharedGameData
     {
         static id sharedInstance = nil;

         static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
      });
        return sharedInstance;
      }




        -(void)launchImage
                     {
                  [GameData sharedGameData].Mainint = [[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]      integerForKey:@"mainint"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"mainint"];
              }
   ```
4. Now go into your AppDelegate.h file and enter this:

   ```
               #import "GameData.h"
   ```
5. Now go into your AppDelegate.m file and enter this in the below method:

   ```
             - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
                 {


                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0  forKey:@"mainint"]; //Add This


              // Override point for customization after application launch.
             return YES;
          }
   ```
6. Now go into your storyboard and drag a UILabel onto your initial View Controller or the View controller that shows first when app is launched. Don't worry we will hide this label so you will not see it.
7. Now drag a UIImageView across the entire screen of your initial View Controller
8. Now go into your initial View Controllers .h file (mine is called ViewController.h) and add the following:

   ```
            #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
            #import "GameData.h" //Add this

          @interface ViewController : UIViewController

          @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *launchImage; //Add this
          @property IBOutlet UILabel *seconds; //Add this
          @property NSTimer *timer; //Add this



                      @end
   ```
9. Now go into your initial view controller .m file (mine is ViewController.m) and add the following:

   ```
                  #import "ViewController.h"


                  @interface ViewController ()

                   @end

                  @implementation ViewController

                 @synthesize launchImage;
                 @synthesize timer;
                 @synthesize seconds;


               - (void)viewDidLoad
            {


              [GameData sharedGameData].Mainint = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    integerForKey:@"mainint"];

                  seconds.hidden = YES;


                  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self   selector:@selector(countUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


                     if ([GameData sharedGameData].Mainint > 3) {

                              launchImage.hidden = YES;
                     }

                          [self countUp];

                           [super viewDidLoad];
                   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.






                                      }




                         - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
                         {
                       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
                  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
                        }









              -(void)countUp
            {


                [GameData sharedGameData].Mainint += 1;
                    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [GameData    sharedGameData].Mainint];


                   if ([GameData sharedGameData].Mainint == 3) {

                     launchImage.hidden = YES;

                      [GameData sharedGameData].Mainint = 4;

                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[GameData      sharedGameData].Mainint forKey:@"mainint"];
                           }



                              }
   ```
10. If you follow those steps exactly it should work and you should have no problems. If something does not work just let me know i'd be happy to help. I searched for days and days trying to find the answer and then finally figured it out through testing this code. Good Luck!